# Anyone know which ESCPOS image command is more common for bluetooth printer?

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, escpos

I have been trying to print logo to an ESC/POS bluetooth printer receipt from my React Native app.
So far I am testing using ESC * command but the end result is not correct, wrong image is printed.
So I am wondering if anybody know which ESC/POS command is the correct one for bluetooth printer.
As note, I am using react-native-printer plugin which is not maintained anymore.

Comment: Printers with a wireless connection such as bluetooth often have limited functions or support special commands due to easy line disconnection and battery operation. It's better to look for device-specific commands than common commands that can be used on any device. It will be easier to get the answer if you add the vendor name, model number, command specification document, etc. of your printer.

Comment: Hi, what we are using right now is all from Chinese manufactured one. They sometimes change their brand but the one I am using right now is Panda PRJ-R58U. And unfortunately they dont have any documents about available commands too

Comment: Perhaps it has to ask the vendor for a specification or switch to a printer from a vendor that publishes the specification. [Panda Pos & Auto Id Solution](https://www.facebook.com/PandaAutoID/)

Comment: hmm ok I will try. thank you